# How to execute a command after a shell script ends and save the output while still showing the results at the screen at the same time

Tags: bash, shell, tee

How can I execute a shell script and save the output to a file while still showing the results in the screen at the same time (both STDOUT and STDERR), and them executing another command after the script ends? Should I use nohup?

Comment: Write a script where you call the first command without nohup.  While it runs it will output to stdout, so on the terminal.  When the first command completes, it will run the second one.  No need for nohup if you are going to wait for it to complete and you want to see the logs anyway.  If you want to keep the logs in a file as well, use `command | tee -a log.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use nohup, you can use a semi-colon inside your script to signal that the a command should be executed after the last one finishes, as shown on test.sh example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
find / -name "*.sh" ; echo END_OF_COMMAND
```

.... them use & to run the script in background with 'tail -f nohup.out' to display the output at the screen while the script is running:

```
$ nohup ./test.sh  & tail -f nohup.out
```

This way you your script would execute the sequence in the background while the output is still showing at the screen.

However, as pointed out using `tee` would be the best approach, to show and redirect to a file both STDOUT and STDERR at the same time you can use tee with the following arguments:

```
$ ./test.sh ; echo END_OF_COMMAND 2>&1 | tee output.log
```